# The smallest, largest and average of array of n size

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, algorithm

The interview question was something like this:

Given an array of some numbers `n` how will you find the `smallest` `largest` and the `average`?

The answer that I made was `sorting the elements of the array` and the `first` element would be the `smallest` and `last` would be the `largest`.

But I was told by the interviewer that sorting (assuming it takes `O(n)` , to find average it might take again `O(n)`). And she added that `she wanted a solution without sorting`.

Any ideas how to do this in `optimally?` . Is there any pre defined algorithm that applies to this case?

(Though I am comfortable with any `C`/`C++`/`Java` answers or even `pseudo codes`, any answers in ***`C#`*** is much appreciated).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just iterate through the array, keeping track of the total, and check at each iteration if the value is smaller than the minimum, or greater than the maximum, and if so, store those as the new min/max.  Average is then just dividing total by the # of items in the array.  That should require only O(n) to do.

Comment: Good approach. But, anything less than `O(n)` ?

Comment: Well you cannot do it less than O(n) as for average you have to go to each item once atleast.

Comment: As No One said, O(n) is the best you can do.

Answer (score 1):

An O(n) algorithm would look like this, no sorting at all:

```
public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        int[] arr = {4, 8, 9, 13, -9, 78, 5};
        FindMinAvgMax(arr);
    }

    public void FindMinAvgMax(int[] a)
    {
        int len = a.Length;
        int sum = 0;
        int min = a[0];
        int max = a[0];
        int avg;

        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            sum += a[i];

            if(a[i] < min)
                min = a[i];
            else if(a[i] > max)
                max = a[i];
        }

        avg = sum /len;

        Console.WriteLine("Min: {0}", min);
        Console.WriteLine("Max: {0}", max);
        Console.WriteLine("Avg: {0}", avg);
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://dotnetfiddle.net/4Bz80E

Answer (score 0):

An interviewer generally expects logic, not shortcuts, because all shortcuts work internally using big logic only, so you should follow the below steps.

This takes O(n).

1. For loop with n times
2. Take first number and compare with all other number, here you will get small and large number
3. At same time use another variable to add all numbers inside that same for loop
4. After for loop you will get smallest, largest as well as addition of all number
5. Then you know to find average(addition/n)...

Here's some code that does this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] a = { 1, 90, 3, 4, 0, 6 };
    int small,big;
    float avg=0;

    small = a[0];
    big = a[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) //O(n) executed n times only
    {
        if (small > a[i])
            small = a[i];
        if (big < a[i])
            big = a[i];
        avg += a[i];
    }
    avg = avg / a.Length;

    Console.WriteLine("smallest= " + small + "  largest= " + big + "  Average= " + avg);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: It is O(n) if the first step is for loop only, not for loop n times, should be a mistake !

Comment: You should perhaps write some code / pseudo-code. Your explanation is a bit unclear.

Comment: @Pham Trung, not n for loop, for loop should execute n number of time(number of inputs)... got my point?

Answer (score 0):

The following code does it with complexity of O(n), while sorting will take O(n* log(n))

```
static void FindLagestSmalestAvg(int[] array)
{
    int smallest = array[0];
    int largest = array[0];
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > largest)
            largest = array[i];

        if (array[i] < smallest)
            smallest = array[i];

        sum += array[i];
    }

    int average = sum / array.Length;

    Console.WriteLine("Smallest = {0}, largest = {1}, average = {2}", smallest, largest, average);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public void find(int[] a)
{

    int sum = 0;
    int min = 9999999; // any very big int
    int max = -999999; // any smallest int
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] < min)
            min = a[i];
        if(a[i] > max)
            max = a[i];
        sum+=a[i];
    }

    avg = sum /i;
    // min will contain smallest num, max will contain largest and avg is avgerage
}
```

Comment: Try to not make a habit of posting code-only answers. It's always good to add a bit of an explanation and justification with it (and not just in comments the code), even if the problem seems trivial to you.